# Libgdx - Problems with render tiledmap (tmx)

Tags: android, mobile, libgdx

When i scrolling my camera the left side erase some images before screen exit.

Why does this happen?

I use tiled map editor and tile size is 32. I try use viewport and get same problem. I try too smaller map and same problem.

My code and gif to the problem:

```
public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter implements InputProcessor {

private TiledMap tiledMap;
private OrthographicCamera camera;
private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;

@Override
public void create() {
    float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

    tiledMap = new TmxMapLoader().load("aventurax.tmx");
    renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(tiledMap);

    float propEsc = h/w;
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, w * propEsc, mapPixelHeight);
    camera.update();
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
}

@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.55f, 0.55f, 0.55f, 1f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    camera.update();
    renderer.setView(camera);
    renderer.render();
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    tiledMap.dispose();
}

@Override
public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
    if(keycode == Input.Keys.LEFT)
        camera.translate(-32,0);
    if(keycode == Input.Keys.RIGHT)
        camera.translate(32,0);
    return false;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try to scale your TiledMap. 
float unitScale = 1 / tileSize; //in your case it's 32
OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map, unitScale);

Comment: what is the value of `mapPixelHeight` ?

Comment: As by calculation you're setting screen height as viewport width of your camera, It's looking illogical ?

Comment: tilePixel w:32 - h:32
mapPixel w:2880 - h:736
gdx.graphics(screen) w: 1794.0 - h:1080.0

Comment: @Ian i try, but my map disappeared...

Comment: @AbhishekAryan 736

Comment: @MatheusMarques same code working for me, may be this is the problem of fps on emulator, Have you tried on desktop or real devices ? Also use `camera.setToOrtho(false, 2880 , mapPixelHeight);`

Comment: @AbhishekAryan in my Samsung S7 i have the same problem...

Comment: I understood now how it works, I had several tiles of various size, I set default to 16x16 and it worked.
Thx